# Is possible to round numbers by default?

Tags: autohotkey

About the round function:

```
N decimal places.
Value := Round(Number [, N])
```

Is possible to set a 'default' behavior to all values, when it has more than [2] places?

As example:

```
x := 9999
y := 3.5
z := x/y
msgbox %z%
```

z outputs: `2856.857143`

My doubt is if it's possible to in such cases `AutoHotkey` auto round the number to [2] places without me explicitly calling the `round` function.

Then z would output `2856.85`.

Where [2] could be any number.

Comment: Can you provide an example with an input number and expected output number?

Comment: @DieissonSilvadosSantos i have add an example.

Comment: Or, if you just wanna keep 2 digits without really rounding, you can just:
n = 2
number = 2856.857143
msgbox % SubStr( number, 1, pos := InStr( number, "." )+n )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you don’t want to have to explicitly call a function for rounding you would use:

```
SetFormat,IntegerFast, .2
```

default is .6 as you probably noticed in your result above

If used in the auto-execute section at the top of the script, it will be used globally across the script if I recall correctly for any math operation. Check out SetFormat in the docs for a full description of the command because it can be used more generally for total width as well.

Answer (score 1):

You may use something like this:

> ```
> x := 9999
> y := 3.5
> z := x/y
>
> msgbox %  "As Function with N = 2:`n"  NRound( z, 2)
> msgbox %  "As Function with N = 3:`n"  NRound( z, 3)
> msgbox %  "As Function with N = 4:`n"  NRound( z, 4)
>
> NRound( number, n ) {
>   main_result     := SubStr( number, 1, pos := InStr( number, "." )+n ) 
>   if ( SubStr(number, pos+1, 1 ) > 5 )
>       main_result :=  SubStr( main_result, 1, -1 ) . SubStr(main_result, -0)+1
> return main_result
> }
> ```